# SIM800L can't send SMS

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I have a SIM800L module (green board). I used [this](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/GSM_SIM800L_Sheild_with_Arduino) to test my module.

In that page, it use a SIM800L red board with a 3.7v LiPo battery. But I directly connected 5v from the Uno to the module.

- GND      >>>   GND
- RX  10       >>>   TX
- TX  11       >>>   RX
- 5v       >>>   Vin

I see "Message Sent Successfully!" message in COM window but nothing happened.

I can not find the problem.

The SIM800L module (green board) specification [is here](http://thecaferobot.com/store/sim800l-gprs-gsm-sms-microsim-module-5v).

The SIM800L module (red-green-blue boards) [is here](http://thecaferobot.com/store/catalogsearch/result/?q=SIM800L).

Comment: I am using A7 board - also have the same problem.. It might be the UNO boards. Voice call works 50% time, GPS location 100%

Comment: What library are you using? check with adafruit [fonaLibray](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FONA)

Comment: https://github.com/cristiansteib/Sim800l

Answer (score 0):

I used a [Power Supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply) and tested the board and SIM800L with it.

At the beginning, the SIM800L only uses a max of 100mA (V = 5v) and after finding the network only 10mA. In this situation the message is sent. I tested it with 4.2v but no message was sent.

It seems it needs 5v to be applied. The 5v of the Uno will be reduced to reach the SIM800L and so no message is sent.